# Server with video files from port speed 1Gbit

Tags: server

My question concerns how many video files I can share on a one dedicated server with 1Gbit link in such a way that the playback of the files does not get stuck. I'm going to create a legal VOD portal with video files up to 2Gb.
I am not experienced, I have not done such divisions before, maybe someone will answer me

Comment: This is off-topic here, maybe try ServerFault.  You aren't going to be able to serve more than 30-40 simultaneous users with a 1 Gb uplink.  You will really need to contract with a Content Delivery Network to set up such a system.

Comment: @antlersoft this question would be off-topic on Server Fault: *"Server Fault is for questions about managing information technology systems in a business environment."*

Comment: @stijn - and isn't that what the question was about-- an IT system to serve video in a V O D business?

Comment: @antlersoft I could be wrong, but I highly doubt OP will be doing this professionally. OP can try posting this on SF, but they're quite strict AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

You need more context in order to have an answer specific to your use case. But the answer is, ***it depends.*** You need to consider the bitrate of your video files and the speed of your computer's hard drive and cpu.

For example, if you have 720p videos at 4mbps a second, you can theoretically support 1000 / 4, or 250 streams from your computer. If you have 1080p videos at 20mbps, you can theoretically support 1000 / 20, or 50 streams on your computer.

You also need to make sure your hard drive can read at speeds greater than 1000 mbps or roughly 100 MB/s.

I apologize as I can't comment due to lack of rep.